# How to make podium with highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, highcharts

this is my chart >> [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ypb6zwd3/2/).
I want to make view like this with highchart
Is that possible to add different picture above the chart like that?
[image]

And I already used dataLabel to show label inside chart.
this is my code:

```
 series: [{
        name: 'RATING',
        data:[
            ['MD', 2],
            ['ML', 4],
            ['SB', 5],
            ['JB', 3],
            ['TB', 1]
            ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'white',
            align: 'center',
            x: 3,
            y: 10,
            style: {
                fontSize: '50px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
            }
        }
    }]
```

but the result become like this:
[image]

Can you give me an advice to solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using highcharts for this? You could quite easily build it using a few `div` and `img` elements, without the need to include an entire charting library.

Comment: I use img and div before i choose to use chart. But when I zoom out or zoom in, the result was messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `useHTML` option to true, and then user [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) to generate images: http://jsfiddle.net/ypb6zwd3/3/

Now just some polishing to place labels the way you want to:

```
            y: 60, // position label in a proper place
            useHTML: true, // required
            overflow: false, //disable overflow
            crop: false, // disable cropping
            formatter: function() {
                  return '<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png" /> <br>' + (6 - this.y);   // <br> tag breaks dataLabel into two lines
            },
```

And now, all you need to do is provide proper image url for each of the columns.

Comment: You are great. But, where is code to turn value 24531 to 42135? Can you show me? And how I can show data MD,ML,SB,JB,TB to data labels?

Comment: Well, just check formatter in my code.. it's this part:  `(6 - this.y)` :) I advice to read about datLabels.formatter in the API - you have access to `this.name` etc.